# which API for a tagCloud to use with play! framework?

Tags: playframework, tag-cloud

I'm implementing a tagCloud for my web application which I'm using play! framework to develop. I just wanted to ask what is the best API to use, I tried to search for online tutorials but i didn't find any. I want to integrate this tagCloud API with a database. so I'm seeking help regarding which API to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Echovoice Tag Cloud generator](https://echovoice.com/demos/tag-cloud). It creates the cloud based on your text and returns a base64 representation of a PNG. The methods can easily be called via JavaScript.

Disclaimer: I made this

Answer (score 0):

I have used a tag cloud from Google Visualisation API - http://visapi-gadgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/termcloud/doc.html.

Its pretty easy to use, just use javascript to output the data and the tag cloud is generated for you client side.